# How to make a phone call that don't show android system view?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I want to make a phone call and by the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));   
startActivity(intent);
```

however, when I use those code to make a phone call, the android will show the system view and I don't see my view.How can I hide the system view and only show my view? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Placing a call will always bring up the in-call screen. If you do not want that, you will need to create your own modified firmware and run it on your own devices.

Comment: you means that if I don't modify the Android system, I have no way to achieve what I want?